# Export to pdf in SharePoint 2010

Tags: export, pdf

I need samples to implement export to pdf in SharePoint 2010. I searched but i can found only samples for asp.net. It will be more helpful if there is reference link or coding for this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to convert Office documents to PDF, you should try the solution from Bamboo - http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-office-to-pdf-conversion.aspx

If you are looking to convert Lists/Views to PDF, you should try the solution from another similar question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841787/export-sharepoint-2007-list-view-to-pdf-and-download-this-via-link

Comment: I need an open source tool..